# Is there a possibility to create Azure Kubernetes Cluster with virtual machine which supports GPU computing for Azure Pass Sponsorship?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, gpu, virtual-machine

I want to create Azure Kubernetes Service resource which supports GPU computing. I have huge amount of data and docker image which requires Nvidia drivers. When I attempt to create it I get:

```
Size not available
This size is currently unavailable in eastus for this subscription: NotAvailableForSubscription.
```

I get this message for every location I choose. I suppose the problem is that I use Azure Pass Sponsorship. Is there any way to do it on this kind of subscription?

Comment: You should contact your sponsor or Azure support

Answer (score 1):

You receive this error when the resource SKU you have selected (such as K8’s Cluster or VM’s) is not available for the location you have selected

You can check the product availability in selected region by [Products available by region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/).

To determine which SKUs are available in a region/zone, use the [Get-AzComputeResourceSku](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azcomputeresourcesku) command. Filter the results by location. You must have the latest version of PowerShell for this command.

```
Get-AzComputeResourceSku | where {$_.Locations -icontains  "centralus"}
```

Refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-sku-not-available) for more information.

Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/api/Redirect/en-in/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/) for a list of common Microsoft Azure limits, quotas and constraints for Azure Sponsorship Subscription.

The following monthly usage quotas are applied. If you need more than these limits, please contact [customer service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/) at any time so that they can understand your needs and adjust these limits appropriately.

Reference: [Microsoft Azure Sponsorship Offer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/offers/ms-azr-0036p/)